# Is it possible to build pyQt with latest Qt (4.8) on latest OSX (10.7)

Tags: pyqt

I have a software that depends on pyQt (it's TortoiseHG and it doesn't support pyside). Is it possible to build pyQt on latest OSX version with latest Qt? I have downloaded pyQt from official website (http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk) but it fails on first, configuration step with "i386 architecture" link error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) has [numerous PyQT builds](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=pyqt) (including version 4.9.1 at time of writing) so it appears to be possible.

If just getting it via MacPorts (recommended) isn't an option, you can examine [their portfile](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/python/py-pyqt4/Portfile) to see how they're configuring and building it, and then do the same locally.